# terraform google cloud nat using reserved static ip

Tags: terraform

We have reserved static (whitelisted) IP addresses that need to be assigned to a CloudNAT on GCP by terraform. The IPs are reserved and registered with a service provider, which takes weeks to get approved and added to their firewalls, so dynamic allocation is not an option.

The main problem for us is that the google_compute_router_nat section requires the nat_ip_allocate_option, but in this case the IP address has already been allocated, so it fails with an error stating exactly that. The only options for allocate are AUTO_ONLY and MANUAL_ONLY, but it seems maybe an EXISTING or RESERVED might be needed, unless I'm missing something obvious.

Here is the failing configuration:

```
resource "google_compute_address" "static_ip" {
  name    = "whitelisted-static-ip"
  region  = "${var.project_region}"
}

resource "google_compute_router_nat" "cluster-nat" {
  name                               = "cluster-stg-nat"
  router                             = "${google_compute_router.router.name}"
  region                             = "${google_compute_router.router.region}"
  nat_ip_allocate_option             = "MANUAL_ONLY"
  nat_ips                            = ["${google_compute_address.static_ip.self_link}"]
  source_subnetwork_ip_ranges_to_nat = "LIST_OF_SUBNETWORKS"
  subnetwork {
    name                    = "${google_compute_subnetwork.service.self_link}"
    source_ip_ranges_to_nat = ["ALL_IP_RANGES"]
  }
}
```

Results in the following error:

```
Error: Error creating Address: googleapi: Error 409: The resource 'projects/staging-cluster/regions/us-central1/addresses/whitelisted-static-ip' already exists, alreadyExists
```

because the static IP resource is already reserved in GCP External IP Addresses and registered with the service provider.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what error you are describing. Can you paste the exact terraform your are running and the full error output?

Comment: Edited to remove the commented out portions of the configuration. Hopefully this is a little clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is with the `google_compute_address resource`, not the NAT. You are trying to create a resource that already exists. Instead you should do one of the following:

- If you want Terraform to manage this resource for you import the resource into Terraform, see here https://www.terraform.io/docs/import/ and here https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_address.html#import
- If you do not want Terraform to manage the IP address for you then you can use a data object instead of a resource object. This is essentially a read only resource lookup so that you can reference it in Terraform but manage it somewhere else. See here https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/data-sources.html and here https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/d/datasource_compute_address.html

Answer (score 2):

Changing the google_compute_address resource to a data object was the magic. I modified it to be:

```
data "google_compute_address" "static_ip" {
  name    = "whitelisted-static-ip"
  region  = "${var.project_region}"
}
```

Where the name of "whitelisted-static-ip" is what we assigned to the reserved external IP address when we created it. The updated router NAT resource then became:

```
resource "google_compute_router_nat" "cluster-nat" {
  name                               = "${var.cluster_name}-nat"
  router                             = "${google_compute_router.router.name}"
  region                             = "${google_compute_router.router.region}"
  nat_ip_allocate_option             = "MANUAL_ONLY"
  nat_ips                            = ["${data.google_compute_address.static_ip.self_link}"]
  source_subnetwork_ip_ranges_to_nat = "LIST_OF_SUBNETWORKS"
  subnetwork {
    name                    = "${google_compute_subnetwork.service.self_link}"
    source_ip_ranges_to_nat = ["PRIMARY_IP_RANGE"]
  }
}
```

which is only a mod to the nat_ips field to point to the data object. Simple two word change and we're good to go. *Excellent!*